# Check if div-container has more than one div-inner no jQuery

Tags: javascript

I need a `if` `else` function that checks if `div_container` has more than one `div_inner` inside of it with Javascript only.

Here's my example code:

```js
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner')
var container = document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML;
if(container > '1') {
  container.classList.add('test');
}
else {
  // do nothing
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
</div>
```

I only want to use Javascript. No jQuery at all.

Comment: Give your outer div and id so you can use getElementById, then you can iterate through the returned childNodes and use nodeName to determine if its a div.

Comment: So select the `container` elements, loop over the collection, check to see if it has elements with that class inside.

Comment: `div_container.querySelectorAll('.inner').length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the container and loop through them to check the inner div's length:

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
container.forEach(function(el){
  var inner = el.querySelectorAll('.inner').length;
  if(inner > 1) {
    el.classList.add('test');
  }
  else {
    // do nothing
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
for (const container of document.querySelectorAll('.container')) {
  if (container.querySelectorAll('.inner').length > 1) {
    container.classList.add('test');
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
  <div class="inner">Test</div>
</div>
```